# How to browse the rows of a column with several types

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to browse the rows of a column with several types To obtain a single value "8G" from file Excel (xls).

This is my code:

```
public String tyer(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell n) {
    String v = "";
    if (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == n.getCellType())
        v = (Integer.toString((int) n.getNumericCellValue()));
    else if (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == n.getCellType())
        v = n.getStringCellValue();
    return v;
}

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    for (int k = 0; k < s0.getLastRowNum(); k++) {
        String g = s0.getRow(k).getCell(1);
        String h = tyer(g);
        if (h.contains("8G")) {
            System.out.println(g);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

that is error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell"

that is example of what i need

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrdGs.png)

tnx for your help

Comment: Can you add exact stack trace here ?

Comment: How exactly i can add stack trace

Comment: Can you paste the full code?